# Message hangs (timeout) when sending from Azure Web App to Azure IoT Hub Devices

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service, iot

Below I present a part of an Azure Web App that handles a device notification logic. What I'm doing is invoking the code shown below from a ASP MVC Controller.
But when I run it I get an hung (ever-pending) request from the browser.

I thought I've found a workaround by wrapping the SendAsync call in a BackgroundWorker thread. It's better, but I doesn't work right. For first couple of times (one or two) it works ok, but then it happens again, the wrapped thread hangs.

The code is not far different from the one on MSDN for a console application. What am I missing?

```
using System.Web.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Azure.Devices;

namespace MyTest
{
    public class Sender
    {
        private readonly string connectionString;
        private readonly Microsoft.Azure.Devices.ServiceClient serviceClient;

        public Sender()
        {
            connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"];
            serviceClient = ServiceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
        }

        public async void SendRequest(string deviceId, string msgText)
        {
            var message = new Message();
            message.Properties.Add("text", msgText));

            await serviceClient.SendAsync(deviceId, message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you try creating a console app and running it from the console app in the website? You can use Kudu's debug console by going to `https://<yourSiteName>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole` and log in with your azure account. The reason I ask this is to try to determin if it's an azure issue or an async/deadlock issue. The behavior you're describing sounds like async deadlock in an ASP.NET thread which would point to a bug in the library you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by inappropriate usage of ASP MVC framework.

It turned out that AsyncController has to be used instead of just Controller when a long running async\await is utilized. The pipeline must be async all the way.

Comment: The whole line has to be async. I had the same problem and I solve it by adding async.